# elasticsearch count number of data in every month

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `*.csv` file like this.

```
id,create_date,data
60,2019/6/12 16:19,A
2,2019/6/12 16:45,A
3,2019/6/13 10:53,A
4,2019/6/20 16:22,A
5,2019/6/26 18:49,B
6,2019/7/8 16:48,B
7,2019/7/8 16:48,B
8,2019/7/8 16:49,A
9,2019/7/8 16:49,B
77,2019/7/8 16:50,B
11,2019/7/8 16:52,B
12,2019/7/8 16:52,B
13,2019/7/8 16:53,B
14,2019/7/8 16:56,B
15,2019/7/8 16:57,B
16,2019/7/8 16:58,B
17,2019/7/8 17:00,B
18,2019/7/9 13:11,B
19,2019/8/12 10:38,B
20,2019/8/12 10:43,B
21,2019/8/12 10:46,B
65,2019/8/12 10:54,B
23,2019/8/12 10:57,B
87,2019/8/1 11:31,B
25,2019/8/5 11:58,B
104,2019/8/14 12:35,B
112,2019/8/17 14:19,B
106,2019/8/17 14:21,B
```

And I've imported it to my elasticsearch as an index using "Upload a file" integration.

[image]

How can I use [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) to find the number of data in every month?

I mean I want a result like this:

```
2019/06: 4 A, 1 B
2019/07: 1 A, 12 B
2019/08: 10 B
```

The result above means that in June 2019, I have 4 `A`s and 1 `B`, and in July 2019, I have 1 `A`, and 12 `B`s ...

I know I can use the following query to count the total number of `A`, and `B`. But have no idea how to count the number of data in every month.

```
GET my_data/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "age_stats": {
      "terms": { "field": "data" }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to count the number of data in every month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

When you imported the data, your date were most likely not properly parsed.

You need to re-import you data but override the import settings.

[image]

And set the format of your date like so:

[image]

Then you will ba able to perform date aggregation.

## Solution

```json
GET /73135106/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "num_doc": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "data",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to say that I imported the csv file using `yyyy/M/d H:mm` format.